# Android GridView visual feedback for item press and release

Tags: android, gridview

I'm porting an app from another platform, and using the GridView to implement the UI for a soundboard.  Each item in the grid is a simple custom layout defined in XML consisting of a RelativeLayout at the root with a child ImageView to hold a bitmap and TextView to hold some text.  The user presses the item and it plays a sound.  All that's working fine.  What is missing is some kind of visual feedback that the GridView item is being pressed and then released.  On the other platform it was relatively trivial to add such an animation.

Does the GridView control on Android have a built-in way to do this, or do I have to roll my own?  I was thinking I could use setOnTouchListener() to get the ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP events, determine the item in the grid it was for, and then apply a ScaleAnimation to the item for each event.  However, that seems overly complicated for what seems like a basic feature.  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom background like this.
Put this to drawable folder.
my_custom_bg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abc_list_pressed_holo_dark" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/defaultbackground" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/defaultbackground" android:state_enabled="true"></item>

</selector>
```

Than use it like this.

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_custom_bg);
```

Comment: This worked great.  I tried using the setOnTouchListener() method I mentioned in my question, but it became unnecessarily complicated.

My selector was pretty much exactly the same, except I used colors in the items (e.g., "@color/my_color_1") instead of a drawable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [setColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter(int)). Enable it on `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and disable it (eg. setting color filter to `null` or calling `clearColorFilter()`) on `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` :)

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know about color filters, so that's helpful.  So, it sounds like there is nothing built into the GridView for visual feedback.  I have to listen for UI events and modify visual state in code.

Comment: That seems to be the case.